# What is the faster way to run an OSM (xml) data to Esri geodatabase data for a big area with FME?

Tags: esri-geodatabase, fme-form, xml, pbf

I am working on OSM highway(polyline) data with respect to the keys Max_speed and surface for the whole Africa. In this case I took at first the  Geometry Filter with line and I used 2 list_searchers for max_speed and surface.I also use 2 attribute_creator for output. This way is working to get a Geodatabase file which i can use on arcmap. But it takes a long time to read the data.

Can anyone help me to give the faster way to run the XML data? OR
the faster way to use PBF format in this purpose?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. [ArcGIS editor for Open Street Map](http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Tools&referringTitle=Documentation) is a extension you can import and load osm directly from the OSM server into the arcmap. I doubt you can import all of the data in the Africa extent with this tool. But there are some tools in the extension you can use it for loading OSM data.
2. If you have performance problem to import xml data in Geodatabase with FME, try to convert xml to another simple formats like **shapefile**, Then import shapefile to a geodatabase.
3. you can download OSM data converted to the shapefile directly from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/africa.html).